# How to send the dynamic values in html form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

This may be a simple one for the expert. But I couldn't get it working.

I have a table in my MySql database with columns: `Score_id` and `Score`.

I am querying this table and displaying the entries in my web page. It looks like this:

Part of php Code:

```
<form method="POST">
$i=0;
while ($i < sizeof($score_id)) { 
    // Display the score data
    echo "<span>$score_id[$i]</span><span>$score[$i]</span>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"delete\" name=\"delete_score\">";
    $i++;
}
</form>
```

Results displayed:

```
Score Id   Score
   1          5      <delete>
   2         50      <delete>
   3         15      <delete>
```

When the user clicks on delete button I want to delete that particular entry from the table.

How do I know the user clicked on particular delete button?(or How to send corresponding `score_id` with post?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize buttons in this case:

```
echo '<form method="POST">';
$i=0;
while ($i < sizeof($score_id)) { 
  // Display the score data
  echo "<span>$score_id[$i]</span><span>$score[$i]</span>";
  echo "<button type='submit' value='".$score_id[$i]."' name='delete_score'>Delete</button>";
  echo '<br/>';
  $i++;
}
echo '</form>';

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');

// same page processing
if(isset($_POST['delete_score'])) {
    $id = $_POST['delete_score'];
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM table_name WHERE score_id = ?';
    $delete = $db->prepare($sql);
    $delete->bind_param('i', $id);
    $delete->execute();

    if($delete->affected_rows > 0) {
        echo 'Delete success!';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 this is just a simple example, just a basic idea how to tackle this, since this is still too broad. can be used as a starting point

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 well, thats a part of answering here on SO. typing fast answers :D

Answer (score 0):

I would name the input fields with for example an Id prefix and then you can loop through the id's + "_delete_score" in your backend to delete it.

```
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"delete\" name=" . $i . "_\"delete_score\">";
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I forgot to mention that I have several forms on the same page. On the submit page I am recognizing the different forms clicked by using: if ($_POST['Name_of_form_button']). In this case how to do it? can you please show how to loop through? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Call a `JS` function and pass the ID of score to delete ....

```
 echo '<input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete_score" onclick(deleteThis('.$score_id[$i].'))>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [w3school best practices](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Score_id,Score FROM my_table ORDER BY Score_id";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    echo "<span>";
    echo $row['Score_id'];
    echo "</span>";
    echo "<span>";
    echo $row['Score'];
    echo "</span>";
    echo "<a href='delete.php?Score_id=".$row['Score_id'].'>Delete</a>"
    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

In the file delete.php you should write a statement which uses parameter $_GET['Score_id'] in a DELETE statement

```
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

       // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE Score_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $score_id);

    // set parameters and execute
    $score_id = $_GET['Score_id'];
    $stmt->execute();

   header('Location: previous_page.php');

    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use GET method.

```
echo "<a href='delete.php?score_id=$score_id'>Delete</a>"
```

Go to delete.php and type this:

```
$score_id = $_GET['score_id'];
```

You can then proceed to delete that particular item in database. Cheers!